# Count number of letters in CMD and batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this project using batch file.My code below can count characters when user type inputs (numbers, letters, symbols),but i want the program count only letters. Can you help me out with this problem. My code is shown below.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo.

:a
REM Set "string" variable
SET /p string="Type characters to Count:"
REM Set the value of temporary variable to the value of "string" variable
SET temp_str=%string%
REM Initialize counter
SET str_len=1

:loop
if defined temp_str (
REM Remove the first character from the temporary string variable and increment 
REM counter by 1. Countinue to loop until the value of temp_str is empty string.
SET temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
SET /A str_len += 1
GOTO loop
)

REM Echo the actual string value and its length.
ECHO %string% is %str_len% characters long!
set /p prompt="Do you want to continue?Y/N:"
if %prompt%==Y goto a
goto b

:b
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:getString
    echo(
    REM Set "string" variable
    set "string="
    SET /p "string=Type characters to Count:"

:calculateLength
    if not defined string ( set "str_len=0" ) else (
        for /f %%a in ('
            cmd /u /v /q /c"(echo(!string!)" %= output unicode string =%
            ^| find /v ""                    %= separate lines =%
            ^| findstr /r /c:"[a-zA-Z]"      %= filter characters =%
            ^| find /c /v ""                 %= count remaining lines =%
        ') do set "str_len=%%a"
    )

:show    
    REM Echo the actual string value and its length.
    ECHO [%string%] is %str_len% letters long!
    echo(
    set /p "prompt=Do you want to continue? Y/n: " || set "prompt=Y"
    if /i "%prompt%"=="Y" goto :getString

    pause
    exit /b
```

This uses a simple trick. If we start a unicode cmd instance, its output (the result from `echo` in this case) is unicode, that is, two bytes per character, usually a null and the real character.

This output is processed by a filter, `more` or `find`, that will process the nulls as line terminators, splitting the output string into lines, one line for each input character.

This set of lines are filtered with `findstr` to only allow letters. The remaining lines are counted with a `find /c /v ""` command that will count non empty lines.

**edited** to adapt to comments.

Input a block of lines and process them

```dos
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%.tmp"

:getString
    echo(
    echo(Please, type your text and end input pressing F6 and Enter
    copy con "%tempfile%" >nul 2>nul

:calculateLength
    for /f %%a in ('
        cmd /u /q /c"(type "%tempFile%")" %= output unicode string =%
        ^| find /v ""                     %= separate lines =%
        ^| findstr /r /c:"[a-zA-Z]"       %= filter characters =%
        ^| find /c /v ""                  %= count remaining lines =%
    ') do set "str_len=%%a"

:show    
    ECHO input data is %str_len% letters long!
    echo(
    del /q "%tempFile%" 2>nul 
    set /p "prompt=Do you want to continue? Y/n: " || set "prompt=Y"
    if /i "%prompt%"=="Y" goto :getString

    pause
    exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer but it should also need to read the spaces including the newline.Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting initial string length to 1 in line

```
SET str_len=1
```

change it to 0 like so:

```
SET str_len=0
```

Comment: Yeah I already changed the value but i want to count the letters only how am i supposed to do that?thanks

Comment: I ran your code and it gave the right count of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Define a string with all letters:
SET letters=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

echo.

:a
REM Set "string" variable
SET /p string="Type characters to Count:"
REM Set the value of temporary variable to the value of "string" variable
SET temp_str=%string%
REM Initialize counter
SET str_letters=0

:loop
if defined temp_str (
REM Get the first character from temporary string variable
SET char=%temp_str:~0,1%
REM If the character is letter, count it
if "!letters:%char%=!" neq "%letters%" SET /A str_letters += 1
REM Remove the first character from the temporary string variable.
REM Countinue to loop until the value of temp_str is empty string.
SET temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
GOTO loop
)

REM Echo the actual string value and its number of letters.
ECHO %string% have %str_letters% letters
set /p prompt="Do you want to continue?Y/N:"
if %prompt%==Y goto a
goto b

:b
pause
exit
```

Comment: it counts the character but the counting is wrong. Do you have any better ideas?