# how to count each letter in a sentence withoud the blank spaces in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to count all the letters that are in a sentence and I am trying to echo it on screen, but I couldn't get it to work I have tried to set a count so it goes up by 1 for each letter but couldn't get it to work. This is my code:

```
@echo off
:loop
SET Input=
set /p Input=jouwscript
IF "%Input%"=="" (
echo Write atleast 1 word
goto loop
) else (
    FOR %%a IN (%Input%) DO (
            ECHO %%a
        )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. BTW, "couldn't get it to work" is hardly a description of the problem... can you be more specific?

Comment: first, remove any spaces: `set "input=%input: =%` (similar with any other chars you don't want to count). Then enter `[batch-file] variable length` in the search box at the top of this site.

Comment: Your question title and description state you wish to count letters, however your code attempts to count the words. Which is it?

Comment: @T3RR0R I am trying to count the letters, I was fiddling with some code to see if it worked

Comment: What is the definition of a `letter`? Is it any printable character? Is it only `[A-Za-z]`? Are any of these to be counted: `0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of letters in CMD and batchfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024071/count-number-of-letters-in-cmd-and-batchfile)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to accept a temporary file, it gets *very* simple:
Just write the string without spaces to a file and get the file size:

```
@Echo off
setlocal
set /p "input=Enter sentence: "
<nul >temp set /p "=%input: =%"
for %%a in (temp) do echo "%input%" has %%~za letters.
```

This counts all characters but spaces (also TABs, numbers, punctuation marks, and even poison chars (like `<>&|%"!`))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that counts characters and words input. Word length maximum of 30 characters assumed. The basis is substring modification with regards to counting letters - iterating over a given number of character spaces and incrementing the letter count for each non empty letter space.

Substring modification is also used to handle the presence of `!` within strings. If you need to count letters only, ignoring characters, you will need to adjust the below to remove non letter characters from the string prior to commencing the nested loop that performs the counts. Alternately, Use findstr to reject any input that contains non letter/ whitespace characters.

```bat
@Echo off
 Call :Getinput Sentence
 Echo(Your Sentence: "%Sentence%"
 Echo(Contains: %WC% Words and %LC% Letters
Goto :Eof

:GetInput
:# Disable DE Environment to allow substitution of ! Expansion character
 Setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:# Nul Letter and Word Count Variables
 Set /A "LC=WC=0"

:# Nul existing variable value
 Set "input="

:# Additional safegaurd; Doublequote input command. 
 Set /P "input=Enter Sentence: "

:# Flag input as not entered if true; exit function
 If Not Defined Input Exit /B 1

:# Substitute exclamations for counting during DelayedExpansion Environment
 Set "input=%input:!=[EXC]%"

:# Allow safe use of input strings, And expansion of current value of variables when modified in code blocks:
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:# Assign Word Value; Modify ! Expansion Char for counting; Count each Character in Word
 For %%W in (!Input!)Do (
  Set "Word=%%W"
  Set "Word=!Word:[EXC]=#!"
  Set /A WC+=1
  For /L %%L in (0 1 30)Do If Not "!Word:~%%L,1!" == "" (
   Set /A LC+=1
  )
 )

:# Exit DelayedExpansion Environments
 For %%i in (1 2)Do Endlocal & (
  Set "LC=%LC%"
  Set "WC=%WC%"
  Set "Input=%Input%"
 )

:# Substitute exclamation marks back into the input string after exiting DE environment
:# Assign value to Arg 1
 Set "%~1=%Input:[EXC]=!%"

:# Flag input as entered
 Exit /B 0
```

output:

```
C:\Users\tcdou>tout
Enter Sentence: test! one
Your Sentence: "test! one"
Contains: 2 Words and 8 Letters

C:\Users\tcdou>tout
Enter Sentence: test! ! two
Your Sentence: "test! ! two"
Contains: 3 Words and 9 Letters

C:\Users\tcdou>
```

Comment: I've added some otuput to the answer @Stephan, would you mind elaborating on the problems with exclamation marks you anticipate?

Comment: Huh? Can't replicate anymore. (strange...) I confirm: working fine.

Comment: (must have messed up my `cmd` window yesterday. Also can't replicate exclamation mark issues with @lit's code that I had yesterday)

Comment: Is it Possible delayed expansion was enabled prior to testing either script?

Comment: that would explain a lot, but I'm not aware I was (I would have had to start `cmd` with the `/v` switch, which I honestly don't remember doing)

Answer (score 1):

As you have not stipulated exactly what you're looking to do, or exactly how you'd like your output, here's something a little bit different to the other current answers:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "input=" & Set /P "input=jouwscript>" & If Not Defined input GoTo :EOF
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('(%%SystemRoot%%\System32\cmd.exe /V /U /S /D /C 
 "Set /P "^=!input: ^=!" 0<NUL"^) ^| %%SystemRoot%%\System32\find.exe /N /V ""'
) Do Set /P "=%%G" 0<NUL & Echo(
Pause
```

*The last line is optional, I've included it only for testing by GUI, (doubleclick).*

---

As an extension of the above idea, you could of course capture each character as a variable too:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Char[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G=") & Set "i=0" 
Set "input=" & Set /P "input=jouwscript>" & If Not Defined input GoTo :EOF
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('(%%SystemRoot%%\System32\cmd.exe /V /U /S /D /C 
 "Set /P "^=!input: ^=!" 0<NUL"^) ^| %%SystemRoot%%\System32\find.exe /V ""'
) Do (Set "Char[0]= %%G" & For /F "Tokens=2 Delims= " %%H In ('Set Char[0]'
    ) Do Set /A i+=1 & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%I In (!i!
    ) Do EndLocal & Set "Char[%%I]=%%H" & Set "Char[0]=")
Echo There were %i% non space characters.
If Defined Char[1] For /L %%G In (1,1,%i%) Do Set Char[%%G]
Pause
```

*Once again, the last line is optional, I've included it only for testing by GUI, (doubleclick).*

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a supported Windows system and are able to use the programs already on it, you could easily do this using a single PowerShell command. This command will replace whitespace (space and tab), then calculate the length of the resulting string.

```
SET "Input=now is the time"
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "('%Input%' -replace '\s+','').Length"') DO (SET /A "COUNT=%%A")
ECHO COUNT is %COUNT%
```